# Matplotlib issue x and y label for multi axes figure

Tags: matplotlib, visualization

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as nm
x = nm.linspace(start=0,stop=20,num=30)
fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0,0.6,0.6,0.4])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0,0,0.8,0.4])
ax1.plot(x,nm.sin(x))
ax1.set_xlabel('x',fontsize=15,color='r')
ax1.set_ylabel('sin(x)',fontsize=15,color='r')
ax2.plot(x,nm.cos(x))
ax2.set_xlabel('x',fontsize=15,color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel('cos(x)',fontsize=15,color='r')
plt.show()
```

The output I am not able to see the xlabel for ax2 and not able to see both y label for ax1 and ax2..The image is present below:
`enter code here`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9bsF.jpg)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you have to use subplots to achive this.

Comment: If you see the image, I have got the xlabel for ax1(axes 1)..

Comment: ax1.yaxis.set_label_text('sin(x)',fontsize=15,color='r') and ax2.yaxis.set_label_text('cos(x)',fontsize=15,color='r') Also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected as you are asking to create an axes that is aligned with the left edge of the figure by using `fig.add_axes([0,...])`. Same thing for the bottom axes, which you have aligned to the bottom-left of the figure using `fig.add_axes([0,0,...])`.

Increase the first value e.g. `fig.add_axes([0.125,...])` to leave room for the axes decorations on the left or bottom of the axes.

It is generally recommended to use the subplots functions (such as [add_subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot), [plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) or [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_and_subplots.html?highlight=gridspec)) so that these details are handled automatically.

Comment: Yes, True thanks,I have added:                       ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.15,0.6,0.6,0.4])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.15,0.1,0.8,0.4]) And it worked for me...